# Hovereffect of button overlaps part of logo

Tags: css

[image]

*EDIT* Changed the text to reflect better the problem.

**For live demo you see the website here: http://wow-klickers.de/ (The CSS here I have modified, to maybe solve the problem.)**

So I have the following scenario. My website contains a navigation bar, which in the picture above contains a "Forum" button and there is above a logo. If I go over the button the hover effect hides the part of the logo which extends into the button. I want to hover over the button but not hide the part of the logo.

Here are my code snippets:

```
<h1 id="logo"> // the blue box of the 2. picture
  <a href="/"></a> // the blue box of the 1. picture
</h1>
```

CSS things:

```
#logo a {
  width: 275px;
  height: 126px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 18px; // added here
}

h1#logo {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 85px;
  top: 6px;
  background: url("images/logo.png") no-repeat;
  width: 275px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2; // changed here
  height: 126px; // added here
}

#primary-menu-bar li a, #primary-menu-bar ul.menu li a {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 29px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

*EDIT* I tried with padding or margin, but with margin my logo is cut off but the logo should overlay over the button. And padding does not work..

Comment: share the markup for the navigation, along with css for those elements.  or can you put up the entire logo + navigation area in jsfiddle? i think your z-index rules need to be changed.  you are placing the logo (z-index 2) on top of the navigation (z-index 1). i need to test using your markup

Comment: I better share the website.. it's easier

Comment: Live site works fine for me (using Chrome)

Comment: Yes but the hover effect of the button overlaps the part of the logo which extends into the button, this should not be

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index:10` to `h1#logo`, and not just on the `a` tag inside.

Comment: That won't work as the logo will obscure the click area of the anchors, unless he wants to use `pointer-events:none` which will not work in IE 10 and under..

Comment: @rgthree, Well yes the top part of the button will link to the homepage. The only real work-around is if he changed the button to include part of the logo, and the logo height would change.

Comment: Yes but I want to press the whole button, not only the bottom part of the button. If I press the button where the logo extends into I click on the link for the logo, but it still should be the link for the button. I hope it's clear, sry for the confusing

Comment: @Michael, that's not going to work and not how `z-index` works, because if you want the logo to sit over the navigation image, then part of the nav link will be obscured by the logo - and link to the homepage.

Comment: @Nick R So the best way is if I make one whole image and integrate my logo into the navbar and then create areas of links. Sadly that there is no  functionality in css.

Comment: @Michael Well - it's one solution anyway, unless anyone suggests anything else?